# How to ping several hosts at the same time (bash) linux

Tags: linux, bash, function, networking, ping

```
ip="192.168.129."
function addToList(){
list="$list $1"

}

addToList $1
for i in $ip{$list}
do
ping -c 1 $ip$1 > /dev/null

echo "Ping Status of $ip$1 : Success" ||
echo "Ping Status of $ip$1 : Failed"
done
```

How can i ping more than one host at the same time and show it in a list which ip address is up or down?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/413367/ping-multiple-ips-using-bash

Comment: Why not keep all IPs in an array?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use a more powerful `ping` tool like [fping](http://fping.sourceforge.net/).

The other approach is to run the pings in the background:

```
for ip in $*; do
    if [[ "$ip" =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]; then
        ip="192.168.129.$ip"
    fi

    (
        ping -c 1 $ip > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "node $ip is up" 
        else
            echo "node $ip is down"
        fi
    )&
done
```

`(...)&` runs a script in the background.

Comment: the list is not working, only the first parameter works.

Comment: Your code is broken. See my edits. `$*` expands to all command line parameters. The `if` prepends the local network if you just call the script with a single number like `1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I wrote after reading a similar post.

https://bitbucket.org/kurtjensen/nettest/src/master/

It can use multiple text files as possible configs and the config files give you a chance to name the ip address more descriptively. The example config files are

- home.txt - Which is the default
- momdad.txt - This is for my parents network
- etc.

So I can run the script at home and just hit enter at the prompt or enter something like "momdad" to switch to a different config fo a different network.